# Not hiding row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a function that hides row from the table. In IE everything works OK, but in Chrome it doesn't hide the row. In debug mode, function hides the row, but when it exits the function it returns the row again. 
Code:

```
function DeleteDocument(obj) {

        var table_cell = $(obj).parent();
        var table_row = $(obj).parent().parent();

        table_cell.text('true');
        table_row.hide();

        if (typeof (SetTickerWithUnsavedTextMessage) != "undefined")
            SetTickerWithUnsavedTextMessage();
    }
```

Comment: can you post what obj is or a fiddle example?

Comment: obj is the object that I have clicked on. The whole function works well, but when passes the line SetTickerWithUnsavedTextMessage it goes to execute:
function onclick(event) {
DeleteDocument(this);
}, and this is where the problem comes.

Comment: If I change onclick to onmouseover everything works fine, but that is not the solution.

Comment: What `SetTickerWithUnsavedTextMessage()` looks like.

Comment: Solved. Problem was that parent field that is hiding also has onclick and it made collation. Changing onclick event to onmousedown solved the problem.